# Can I Refactor This Code into a Separate File?

Tags: flutter, refactoring, stream-builder

I've created a Flutter method to build a custom dropdown menu list in my project. The method uses a StreamBuilder to read a Firebase Realtime Database node, and then builds a list of strings based on the document names within that node. It then returns a dropdown menu with the list of strings as menu items.

I have a form that needs four of these drop-downs. The method shown below works as expected, but it's pretty long - and there are four copies of it in this file, along with all of the form code. The entire file runs to about 600 lines, which is way longer than I like.

I'm looking for some guidance on how to refactor this thing. Any advice is appreciated.

EDIT: To be clear, I understand the **concept** of refactoring the code (i.e. cut it out of the main file and put it into a separate file so I can call it easily and reuse it) - I just don't quite grok how to do it with this *particular* piece of code. There seem to be too many arguments needed to successfully build four different buttons with custom menus, and I need the dropDown() method to return a StreamBuilder - but I also need it to return the selectedValue, and I can't figure out how to do both of those things.

```
StreamBuilder<DatabaseEvent> jobDropDown() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: jobsPathRef.onValue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        final data = snapshot.data;
        final Map<Object?, dynamic>? jobData;
        if (data == null) {
          jobData = null;
        } else {
          jobData = (snapshot.data!).snapshot.value as Map<Object?, dynamic>?;
        }
        if (jobData == null) {
          // show noData view
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              children: const [
                Text(
                  'No Jobs Yet!',
                  style: TextStyle(color: CustomColors.fbGrey),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else {
          final jobObjects = <Job>[];
          final jobList = <String>[];
          jobData.forEach(
            (key, value) {
              final dataLast = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
              final job = Job(
                id: dataLast['id'],
                name: dataLast['name'],
                currentBalance: dataLast['currentBalance'],
              );
              jobObjects.add(job);
              jobList.add(job.name);
            },
          );
          jobList.sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b));
          jobList.insert(0, 'Add a new job...');

          return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton2(
              isExpanded: false,
              hint: Text(
                'Job',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                ),
              ),
              items: jobList
                  .map((item) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(
                          item,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ))
                  .toList(),
              value: selectedJob,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedJob = value as String;
                });
              },
              buttonHeight: 40,
              buttonWidth: 200,
              itemHeight: 40,
              dropdownMaxHeight: 200,
              searchController: jobController,
              searchInnerWidget: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 8,
                  bottom: 4,
                  right: 8,
                  left: 8,
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: jobController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10,
                      vertical: 8,
                    ),
                    hintText: 'Select a job...',
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
                return (item.value
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .contains(searchValue.toLowerCase()));
              },
              //This to clear the search value when you close the menu
              onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
                if (!isOpen) {
                  jobController.clear();
                }
              },
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: create a generic dropdown that you can reuse it not only for job but can be reused to whatever type that needs dropdown. [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ikg7vHJoZjA&t=244s&ab_channel=Flutter) is a greate tutorial on how to create generic type

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your jobDropDown method into Stateless/Stateful widget based on your needs. *Write it in different file like `job_dropdown.dart`. If you need some to pass some props/field look at the example.

```
class JobDropDown extends StatelessWidget {
  const JobDropDown({ super.key, required this.exampleField, this.example});

  final SomeType exampleField;
  final SomeTypeNullable? example;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      // rest of your code here
    );
  }
}
```

2. Use it wherever you want like this. /If there's an error make sure you imported the file/:

```
import 'yourpath/job_dropdown.dart'

class MyOtherWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyOtherWidget({ super.key });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        // Some widgets here
        JobDropDown(exampleField: someValue)
        JobDropDown()
        JobDropDown()
        JobDropDown()
        JobDropDown()
      ]
    );
  }
}
```